# image disappears in CSS. Background & Logo

Tags: html, css, image

The basis for my homepage seemed finished when I altered a couple of the headings. Next thing I know, the banner/background image at the top has vanished as well as the logo that sits above it.

I'm pretty sure it's an issue with regards to the CSS. Yet, I can't see what I have changed that has caused this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I've got the background image back now after utilising HTML images instead of CSS. I altered the z-index on the banner to 0 and this then displayed the banner. So naturally I have the header (white box) as z-index: 1 and the logo as z-index: 2.

So if it was all linked to the z-index then in theory my logo and header box should display above the banner now. Yet, they're still missing.

```css
@fontface {
    font-family: Swisz;
    src: url(fonts/swisrg.ttf);
}
@fontface {
    font-family: Swiszt
    src: url(fonts/swist.ttf);
    font-weight: thin;
}

body, html {
    background-color: #d83030;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* the first missing images is the background of the banner container below */
#container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url:"images/banner.jpg";
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    content: 60px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 5px #73008C;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    z-index: -3;
}

#header {
    position: static;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
/*as well as the logo that can be found in the HTML*/
#logo {
    position: relative;
    border: 0px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#nav01 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #374754;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 85px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px
}

ul#menu {
    font-family: "Swisz";
    position: relative;
    background-color: #374754;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

ul#menu li a {
    background-color: #374754;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    font-style: bold;
    background-color: #d83030;
}

#overlay {
    font-family: "Swisz";
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 250px;
    bottom: 200px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: #d83030;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#info {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 450px;
  top: 410px;
}

body {
    font-family: "Swisz", Helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d83030;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26pt;
}

h2 {
    font: "Swiszt";
    font-variant: "thin";
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

h4 {
    font-family: Swisz;
    color: #374754;
    text-align: center;
}

h5 {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #374754;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#sub {
    position: relative;
    color: #374754;
    top: 920px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    size: 40;
}

#hiddenbox {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 298px;
    background-image: url("hidden_bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

p {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}

.pagedown {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


#footer {
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>SITE- This is our website</title>
  <link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="Script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

 <div id="header">
  
  <div id="logo">
/* the logo is below*/
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="SITE" style="width: 321px; height: 72px"></img>

  </div>

 </div>

</div>

<nav id="nav01"></nav>

<div id="overlay">
 
 <h1>SPECTACULAR BIG HEADING<h1>

 <h2>THE FUTURE IS HERE</h2>

</div>

<div id="info">
<img src="seehow.png" alt="See How" style="width: 345px; height: 240px">

</div>

 <div id="main">

  <h1>WELCOME TO WEBSITE</h1>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut turpis sapien. Proin tempus nibh ac rhoncus congue. Nullam pretium placerat vestibulum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed sed est vitae libero placerat tristique. Aliquam pulvinar convallis mi, vitae consequat tortor pellentesque ut. In lacinia, ex vel accumsan viverra, est ex efficitur justo, pulvinar luctus mi leo nec risus. Sed nec tellus bibendum, convallis enim at, elementum lectus. Fusce eu enim blandit, volutpat eros lobortis, auctor odio. Praesent tristique sem elit, nec consequat tortor placerat at.</p>

  <img src="wilfcent.png" alt="Wilf" style="width:345px;height:428px">

</div>

<div id="sub">

<div id="hiddenbox">
  <br>
 <br>
  <p2>Open up new business avenues</p2>
 <br>
  <p2>Review your acquisitions</p2>
 <br>
  <p2>Monitor events</p2>

  <img src="promo.png" alt="Promotion" style="width:321px;height:176px"></img>


 </div>

 <img src="pagedown.gif" alt="Page down" style="width:100%;height:68px"></img>

 <h1> How It Works </h1>
<br>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut turpis sapien. Proin tempus nibh ac rhoncus congue. Nullam pretium placerat vestibulum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed sed est vitae libero placerat tristique. Aliquam pulvinar convallis mi, vitae consequat tortor pellentesque ut. In lacinia, ex vel accumsan viverra, est ex efficitur justo, pulvinar luctus mi leo nec risus. Sed nec tellus bibendum, convallis enim at, elementum lectus. Fusce eu enim blandit, volutpat eros lobortis, auctor odio. Praesent tristique sem elit, nec consequat tortor placerat at. Nullam eu arcu et ex iaculis feugiat ut quis enim. Nulla quis libero placerat, accumsan nulla et, laoreet magna. Sed congue ut nunc maximus gravida.</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
 <footer id="foot01"></footer>

</div>

<script src="Script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks like maybe this line: `url:"images/banner.jpg"` should have parenthesis like `url("images/banner.jpg")`

Comment: I've tried that and still no such luck. I'm baffled as to why it affects the logo too. Thanks for a quick reply though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
background-image: url:"images/banner.jpg";
```

Correct code:

```
background-image: url("images/banner.jpg");
```

Comment: I've since corrected it to be:
#container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url("images/banner.jpg");

Yet the issue is still there, no banner, no logo.